# Why does my Galaxy Note 3 have the same DP dimensions as a much smaller phone?

Tags: android, screen-size, dimension, screen-density

I have been reading about `dp, px, ppi` and `dpi` for awhile now, and I am lost.

Why is it that a large phone like the `Galaxy Note 3` (with a 5.7 `inch` display) can have the same `dp` as a `Moto X` (with only 4.7 `inches`)?

My calculation for each returns a `width=360dp` and `height=640dp`. It seems like many higher density phones fall in this range. Is this true or am I misunderstanding `dp`?

I am using the following to calculate my values: [How to determine the screen width in terms of dp or dip at runtime in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465680/how-to-determine-the-screen-width-in-terms-of-dp-or-dip-at-runtime-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's not just a matter of screen size, it is also a matter of screen density. I'll explain. The convertation formula from px to dp units is as follows:

dp = px * 160 / dpi, where dpi is your screen density.

Consequently, from the values you calculated (let's take the width) we have the following values for the screen density:

Galaxy Note 3 (width = 1080 px): dpi = 1080 * 160 / 360 = 480

Moto X (width = 720 px): dpi = 720 * 160 / 360 = 320.

Galaxy Note 3 and Moto X have the same width = 360 dp because of equal width/dpi ratio  = 2.25 (same for the height/dpi ratio  = 4). Now imagine Moto X has the same density as Galaxy Note 3. In that case you'd get a smaller width = 240 dp for Moto X.