# Why is the layouts put the other way despite the attributes?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Why does this layout seems to inverse what I put as attributes?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="600dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_left"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    >
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/green”
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/top_left"

    >
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/red"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I was expecting that it would be something like:

```
_____400_________200__
|              |      |
200 top_left   |      |400
|______________|      |
               |      |
               |      |
               |      |
               |______|
```

But I get:
[image]

Comment: you are expecting the red color to be below the green right ?

Comment: May I suggest you to use a LinearLayout as the main container with weightSum attribute and finally the 2 View as child?

Comment: @Darkie:I am expecting 400dp goes to green and 200dp goes to red in width. No overlay

Comment: Use android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/top_left"  in your second LinearLayout :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:background="#00FF00" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're putting a 400x200 green rectangle down, aligned to the top of the `RelativeLayout`.

Then you're putting a 200x400 red rectangle down, aligned to the right of the `RelativeLayout`. There's not 600 dp of screen space, so it goes over the top (if there was more than 600 dp, you would get a gap between the two).

If you want them not to overlap, you need to tell the `RelativeLayout` that, by using `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/top_left"`. That will force the red rectangle to start to the right of the green rectangle. In your case, it will probably force the red rectangle off-screen, because there's not enough space for both of them.

Comment: If I add `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/top_left"` to the second one it dissappears

Comment: Yes - it's getting pushed off screen, as I mentioned. Try rotating your device to look at it in landscape mode and you should see what I mean. You need to make the green rectangle smaller, or use a device with a bigger screen!

Comment: But why is it pushed out? Shouldn't it be 400dp for the first and then alocate 200dp for the second = 600dp which is total width?

Comment: What is the total width of the screen you are looking at, in dp? (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465680/how-to-determine-the-screen-width-in-terms-of-dp-or-dip-at-runtime-in-android for how to get it). I suspect it's smaller than you think.

Comment: What I pasted as a screenshot is the design preview