# Full-width AdMob native ads for Android using Google Mobile Ads SDK for Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, googleads-mobile-unity

I am trying to create a native ad like this:

```
nativeExpressAdView = new NativeExpressAdView(adUnitId, new AdSize(360, 150), AdPosition.Bottom);
```

Instead of hardcoding the screen width as 360, I would like to use the full-width available on the device. Smart banners work great for banner ads, but passing `AdSize.SmartBanner` as second argument does not work here.

`Screen.width` returns actual pixels.

Is there a way to obtain the width in dp that I can pass onto the AdSize constructor?

Comment: possibile duplicate. see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465680/how-to-determine-the-screen-width-in-terms-of-dp-or-dip-at-runtime-in-android

Comment: @an_droid_dev not exactly. My question is with respect to googleads-mobile-unity sdk.

Comment: Have you tried `Screen.width` and `Screen.height`? There is also `Screen.resolutions`

Comment: Screen.width returns width in actual pixels. I need width in dp.

Comment: What language/s is this? I think you should tag that to let people know which language are you expect the answer in.