# How to set different size value for same density for different tablet size?

Tags: android, android-layout, tablet, dimension

I have 3 different dimension xml . when I set dimens for xlarge , big tablet looks fine but small tablet not fit -last item shrinking- because both of them getting value same xml "xlarge".

[![1536*2048 320dpi 7''][1]][1]

its looking like that in small tablet . 1536*2048 320dpi 8.9''

[![2560*1800 320dpi][2]][2]

and big tablet. 2560 * 1800 320dpi 10.1''

I have to set different size value for same resolution but different tablet size .

Thanks for helping .

Comment: From your description, the two tablets have different resolution, but same density. So I think what you mean is **setting different size value for same density for different tablet size**. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use device size qualifier, for example:

- large/dimension.xml for 7'' tablet
- xlarge/dimension.xml for 10'' tablet

Or else use new size qualifiers suggested by Google, refer [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts).

So for your devices:

- 7'' tablet : 1536*2048 320dpi = 768dp * 1024dp
- 10'' tablet : 2560 * 1800 320dpi = 1280dp * 900dp

You can use, for example:

- sw768dp/dimension.xml for 7'' tablet
- sw900dp/dimension.xml for 10'' tablet

Comment: nothing change . I try both "xlarge-large dimensions and sw768-sw900dp" but two device getting value same xml file. -xlarge and sw900dp- . device's density is same each other .

Comment: @dev5151 Could you run the code snippet from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11755265/1093344  to get width and height in dp unit?

Comment: 850*1280 & 720*1024

Comment: @dev5151 So you can use sw720dp/dimension.xml for 1536*2048 320dpi 8.9'' and sw850dp/dimension.xml for 2560 * 1800 320dpi 10.1'' .