# Dynamic height of ImageView in scrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to add 3-4 imageviews in a scroll view. Imageviews have dynamic heights. Height of first view have 70% of the screen and second and third have 30% height. I am using constraint layout and guidelines but the height is getting set according to the height of the scroll view but not according to the screen height. Is there a way to do this with constraint layout.

Comment: have you tried it with nested scrollview ?

Comment: yes i did, but it was the same.

Comment: Paste layout code. I think you might have an issue with the height of the scroll view.

Comment: Please send your .XML file, i will you back with correction and working good..

Comment: I did it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing it programmatically?

First, get the Screenheight for your device: [How to determine the screen width in terms of dp or dip at runtime in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465680/how-to-determine-the-screen-width-in-terms-of-dp-or-dip-at-runtime-in-android)

Secondly, get your Imagview and set its height according to xx% of the determined screen height.

BR